# How can I embed a Stack Exchange question inside my blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I love to save my favourite questions and show them off on my blog, eg. wordpress.com blog. How can I embed questions?

Answer (score 13):

You want [Stack Tack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere).

It's a neat app written using the API.

> StackTack is a widget for bloggers and writers to easily tack questions and answers from the StackExchange sites such as StackOverflow, ServerFault and SuperUser, into their articles. The widget remains up to date as answers get added, modified, voted on and accepted.

Comment: StackTack is nice! I'm looking on StackTack website for a page to generate the HTML scripts for a given StackExchange id but I give up. Do you know if it exists?

Comment: @Nam, sorry but I do not.  You should try to contact the author(s).  They would know better.

Answer (score 3):

Every question has an [RSS feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/67268). I'd expect that would be the most appropriate way to do it. *How* to do it depends largely on the blogging platform you're using. If it happens to be WordPress, then I suggest that http://wordpress.stackexchange.com would be the place to ask: "How do I embed an RSS feed into my blog?"

Answer (score 0):

StackTack is just for self-owned blog. For blogger on wordpress.com like me (NOT wordpress.org), I prefer to use [Stack2Blog](https://stackapps.com/questions/611/stack2blog-turning-your-answers-into-blogs-source-code-released).